# Joining values of a column with each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of products. There are two categories, main product and side product as modifiers in a column of table in SQL Server. I am representing main product as P and Modifiers as M here. I have a transaction level data where in single transaction a customer have bought multiple Products with Modifiers. For a single Product there can be multiple Modifiers. Just for reference.

```
Sr No.    Products
1            P1
2            M1
3            M2
4            M3
5            P11
6            M11
```

Now I want to map Products with Modifiers. Each and every Modifiers belongs to the Products above it in the column. The output that I need is like.

```
Product   Modifiers
P1          M1
P1          M2
P1          M3
P11         M11
```

I have already written a logic in sql server using while loop. But it is taking a lot of time to implement the logic. Whereas in my table I have around more than a crore records. Can anyone help me find the efficient way of implementing the logic for above scenario.

Comment: Why doesn't P1 take M11 as a modifier? Why doesn't P11 have M1 as a modifier? Are there columns explaining this relationship missing from your sample? What is the logic to join these to get these results?

Comment: _"I have already written a logic in sql server using while loop"_ Please show us your code, cause I don't get the logic here.

Comment: @JNevill as I have mentioned, every modifier after the product belongs to the product right above it. If a customer buy any product with modifiers system represent it in the tabular format as with Product as first category and whatever the modifier is taken with that particular product will come under that product.

Comment: Is it always true that the P appearing first in the column, with respect to M values, has a lesser value that a P later in the column?

Comment: @nealkernohan yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks tricky, but you can assign a group by using a cumulative sum of the products and then assigning the product to everything in that group:

```
select product, modifer
from (select max(case when product like 'P%' then product end) over (partition by grp) as product,
             product as modifier
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when product like 'P%' then sr_no end) over (order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where modifier not like 'P%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor twist to Gordon's solutions.

**Note:** This assumes every product has at least one modifier.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Product = max(case when Products like 'P%' then Products end) over (Order by [Sr No.] )
              ,Modifiers = Products
         From YourTable
       ) A 
 Where Modifiers <> Product
```

**Returns**

```
Product Modifiers
P1      M1
P1      M2
P1      M3
P11     M11
```